# Contact filters in careers messages aren't working

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

This has arrived in my mailbox today

```
...

My number is (XX) XXXX XXXX or <phone temporarily hidden>.
```

Hit-rate: 50%.
Game over.

And, I suppose there's no point in complaining that suggested position is totally unrelated to anything I ever did at any point in my life.

Comment: If it's totally unrelated, why did you list it? I smell a bug report here, but it's kind of difficult to make out.

Comment: @Tim Why did I list what? Anyway, pay no attention to the last sentence, that's just me nagging :)

Comment: If you have the ringer on, you can call it and it won't be hidden any more. Problem solved.

Comment: @random Mods are being cryptic today :) Ringer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our scrubber has been updated for this specific case.  It will be live later today.